# Recreating stage gives different positions on Safari and Chrome

Tags: konvajs

I am building an WordPress site where in the admin side you can create a canvas and get it rendered on the frontend.

The way I do this is by using the `exportJSON()` method to save the stage,

in the loading process I loop through the stage object that is saved and add all nodes dynamically.

The entre canvas is built with Stage -> Layer[] -> Group(Transformer, Node). So I create a group containing either a Text node or an Imagenode, create a transformer and put the node inside. Then I put this group in a layer.

So in the loop I basically do this:

```
for(const layer of stage){
   const newLayer = Konva.Layer(layer.attrs)
   for(const group of layer.children){
      const newGroup = new Konva.Group(group.attrs)
      for(const node of group.children){
         if(node.className === 'Transformer') continue
         const shape = new Konva[node.className](node.attrs)

         const transformer = new Konva.Transformer({id: 'transformer-' + shape.id(), ...DEFAULT_TRANSFORMER_ATTRS})
         transformer.nodes([shape])
         
         newGroup.add(transformer)
         newGroup.add(shape)
      }
      newLayer.add(group)
   }
   stage.add(layer)
}
```

This works perfect, however this yields different results in Safari vs Chrome.

It looks like this only affects the Text node, and also only the Y position.

See images:

This one is from the WP admin, where I change the canvas how it should look like frontend:

[image]

This one is from Chrome:

[image]

And this one is from Safari:

[image]

The difference might not be significant on a screen, but when it should be on a line it's definitely noticable. Especially since this is later on being printed, the difference is around 1-2cm off.

I am loading the stage like this to get the transformer, and also images to reload all sources. This works fine and that's why I leave it out from my example code

Any idéas here?

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-babbage-4nqjho?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you make an online demo with JSON example loading to compare differences?

Comment: Hello @lavrton and thanks for taking your time. I have updated the post with a sandbox link (https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-babbage-4nqjho?file=/src/index.js).

If you open this in chrome and then safari you will see the difference, the line is for reference

EDIT: I might add that if I generate a PNG it alwasys shows what's on the canvas currently. So the PNG differs aswell if you print it on chrome vs safari

Comment: Is there any chance that this is an async issue? Like the font has not fully arrived in the Safari case when the canvas content is output or measured? Ignore this - I just looked at the sandbox demo and the font is Times New Roman.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Not sure, I don't think so since even if I remove the fontFamily and it should use the default one it differs.

Comment: Can you try this canvas text measuring sample in Chrome and Safari and tell me if the measurements differ? https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/bGBNzyB

Comment: @VanquishedWombat All of the numbers inside the parentheses are the same on chrome and safari. Not sure if it has to do with using a group or something?

Comment: @lavrton, please see this very simplified example. Notice the space between the border and the text. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-waterfall-h5uv54

Comment: @elmgren I am not sure what can I do from konva side :(